# PHP / HTML select options to radio buttons

Tags: php, html

I am trying to convert SELECT options to RADIO buttons. but when I post form, I get nothing. I think it is because different reaction when [] exist in select name and radio name? how should I change server-side POST code?

```
<?php
foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</td>
          <td><select name="option[<?php echo $option['option_id']; ?>]">
              <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
              <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
              <?php echo $option_value['prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>
              <?php } ?>
              </option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

tried:

```
    <?php
    foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</td>
              <td>
                <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?><?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?><?php echo $option_value['prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?><?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

server code:

```
<?php
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                    if (isset($_POST['option'])) {
                        $option = $_POST['option'];
                    } else {
                        $option = array();  
                    }
        }
        print_r($option);
        ?>
```

Comment: I can't see any errors. The code should work. Have you tried a var_dump($_POST) to see what you are posting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to examine the contents of each field separately, e.g. `$_POST['option1']`.

In a loop, this would look something like:

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
    if (isset($_POST['option' . $option['option_id']])) {
        print_r($option);
    }
}
```